# The use of the verb "tell" with a direct object in context

Tags: grammar

Tell me please of I have to use *them* in the following context.

> I learned a few word, but I can't tell you (**them**) off the top of my head.

Does the sentence sound more natural without it?

Comment: You can use ***tell*** intransitively (with no explicitly specified object) where the intended sense is ***divulge** [a secret]* (as in *I know you did something bad, but I won't tell*). or ***perceive, know, be aware of*** (as in *It's no use denying it. I can tell it was you who did it*). But in your context, the sense is more ***list, enumerate, name** [multiple items]*, where it's not idiomatic to omit the subject (***them***, here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Tell* works like *give*, so it can have two objects

- an indirect object, which is the person you are telling

and

- a direct object, which is the thing you are telling the person.

> Give me(indirect object) the schedule(direct object).
>
> Tell me(indirect object) the schedule(direct object).

---

If you do not mention what you're telling, then you are emphasizing the person you're telling instead of what you are telling.

> ... but I can't tell you them (but I can tell you other things).
>
> ... but I can't tell you (but I can tell other people something).

Comment: This answer is not correct. It's the other way round. I've suggested an edit.

Comment: I always get direct and indirect mixed up.  Thanks.